# How to simulating a turn radius

Tags: physics, game-physics

Hi I trying to simulate a vehicle turning around a radius. This is what I'm currently doing

1. Calculate the radius of the turn.
2. Calculate acceleration and add to velocity.
3. Use velocity magnitude to determine distance traveled in one update.
4. Use `arctan( distanceTraveled / turnRadius )` to get the angle of rotation.
5. Update vehicle angle.
6. Rotate velocity by vehicle angle. e.g. `velocity *= Quaternion.AngleAxis(angle, Vector3.up)`
7. Update vehicle position with velocity.

I'm currently getting a lot of drift and not driving straight. Any ideas how to correctly implement this?

Answer (score 0):

```
1. Calculate the radius of the turn.
2. Calculate acceleration and add to velocity.
3. Use velocity magnitude to determine distance travelled in one update.
```

So far, so good.

```
4. Use arctan( distanceTraveled / turnRadius ) to get the angle of rotation.
```

Hold on. First, this conflicts with step 2. Either you're using acceleration to *produce* a turn, or you're using the geometry of a circle to *impose* a turn. If you try to mix these you'll get drift at best. Second, you shouldn't use arctan here, it's just angle=(distanceTraveled/radius).

```
5. Update vehicle angle.
```

Are you keeping track of bearing and attitude separately? That is, can you simulate a car skidding sideways? Or do you assume that the car is pointing in the direction it's moving? If the latter, then you're keeping redundant copies of the same information, which invites bugs.

```
6. Rotate velocity by vehicle angle. e.g. velocity *= Quaternion.AngleAxis(angle, Vector3.up).
```

This should have been covered by step 2, if you did step 2 correctly.

```
7. Update vehicle position with velocity
```

Sounds reasonable.

Answer (score 0):

```
1. You want to calculate the radius of the turn, what do you know to calculate it?

2. You can calculate the acceleration by the formula: a = v²/r , here is v the velocity of the rotating object, r is the radius.

3. The distance is just the velocity times the time travelled.

4. The angle of rotation can be calculated by:

   the "travelled" angle per second = w = 2*pi*revelotions per second "n"
         w= 2*pi*n
w*t="travelled" angle = angle
angle = 2*pi*n*t

we also know that= v = 2*pi*r*n  n=v/(2*pi*r)
You can put that in the formulo for the angle in function of the velocity.

5. I think it is answerred in 4.

6. you have to use sin and cosine to calculate the components of the velocity on every axis. If you know what derivatives are you can use them to calculate the tangence line on the circle where the object moves on. The velocity is in the same direction of the tangence line.


Hope this helped
```